# msbuild Too many conditional symbols CodeGear.Delphi.Targets Delphi XE7 Win2k3 Server

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to get my project compiled automatically. I already found that rsvars.bat needs to be run first. So I have a batch file that contains:

> call "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
>
> msbuild /t:Build /p:config=Release MyProject.dproj

But I got an error as follows:

> Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 28.0
>    Copyright (c) 1983,2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
>   C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(334,5): error E2163: Too many conditional symbols [D:.....myproject.dproj]
>   Done Building Project "D:...myproject.dproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "D:...myproject.dproj" (Build target) (1) ->
>   (_PasCoreCompile target) ->
>    C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\BinCodeGear.Delphi.Targets(334,5):
>   error E2163: Too many conditional symbols [D:....myproject.dproj]
>
> 0 Warning(s)
>      1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.62

Windows 2003 Server R2 Sp2 Enterprise Edition.

What I found is that msbuild.exe on that computer is 3.5.30729.1.
And msbuild on my win7 64bit has newer build no: 3.5.30729.4926 and differs with size.

What can I do about that? To get this work on that win2k3 server? I already tried with msbuild from .net 4.0 folder and got the same result.

Comment: Could it be this issue? http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=62373

Answer (score 1):

You need to go project-> Option-> Conditional Defines and delete the old one Conditional Defines like _VER6. Because that Conditional Defines will create automatically by the Delphi IDE.

Basically it called memory overflow, so in that case you need to solution is to reduce the number of conditional compilation symbols contained on the command line (or in configuration files) by him self.